# Area of a circle smaller than one?

Tags: circles, area, paradoxes

If a circle has radius less than one, does it mean that the circumference of the circle is bigger than the area? How can that even be possible?

For example, if a circle has radius $0.5$, then the circumference is $2 \pi \cdot 0.5 = \pi$, and the area will be $\pi \cdot 0.5^2 = 0.25 \pi$. How can this be the case?

Comment: A straight line can have infinite length and no area enclosed within it. Why would this seem impossible to you?

Comment: Ok I see thanks

Answer (score 4):

You are comparing apples to oranges. Using the metric system, the circle has radius $r \text{ cm}$, while the circle has area $\pi r^2 \text{ cm}^2$. You can use the imperial system with $\text{in}$ and $\text{in}^2$, and they are still different units.

The units for length and area will always be different.

And what's wrong with an area smaller than $1$? If a square has area $0.25$, that means that its area is $0.25$ smaller than a square with area $1$. If I measure the area of your home in $\text{km}^2$, unless your home is $1 \text{km}$ by $\text{1 km}$, then your home will have an area smaller than $1 \text{ km}^2$.

Comment: Okay thanks I see

Comment: No problem, we all have 'brain farts'. Next time you can search up your question on the Internet, or just explain what you found difficult about the problem. From your questions it seems like you know much, much more than this level.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, the units can have an affect on the ratios

For circumference of a circle $C=2\pi r\quad$ for area $A=\pi r^2\quad$ for ratio
$$R=C/A=\frac{2\pi r}{\pi r^2}=\frac{2}{\pi r}\quad \land\quad r=1\implies R=\frac{2}{3.14\cdots}\approx 0.64$$

Management says the measure was in yards but should have been in feet

$$r=3\implies  R=\frac{2}{3.14(3)\cdots}\approx 0.21$$

Management now says it WAS feet and should have been in yards $\quad (1/3$ that of feet)

$$r=1/3\implies  R=\frac{2}{3.14(1/3)\cdots}\approx 1.91$$

So yes. If your radius is less than one, circumference can be larger than area.